# About providing useful resources at our help-center

Tags: discussion, help-center

After the question in our site - [Where can I find/get basic information about Hinduism on the web?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10599/277), and recent [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/conversation/about-providing-useful-resources), I think if we can provide **useful resources** in our help center (as recently discussed on MSE - [How can we add a “useful resources” to the help center?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279847/260388)).

So, how about providing such stuff in our help-center? Also what information should we provide?

<sup>Note: I've post two answers in which one suggests **Yes** to provide useful source and another suggests **No**. (Vote to one which you prefer)</sup>

Comment: Also see http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53/acceptable-sources-and-citations

Comment: It is a good idea. There is lot more in Hinduism as compared to Buddhism. Can it all fit in one page? From the top of my head, there can be references to Vedas, Upanishads, Itihasas, Puranas; sites related to Shiva, Vishnu and Devi. I saw meditation and retreat related links on Buddhism site but I think those are considered off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**<sup>*</sup>, It is a great idea to provide useful resources in the help-center. The resources are expected to be helpful in the following ways:

- New users to get started by getting basic information and philosophy about Hinduism.
- To find and get the popular and frequently used (text) scriptures on the various topics and philosophies from good resources.
- Providing resources for commonly used practices

In brief resources should be so useful that user can understand and learn the key beliefs, practices and philosophies from knowledgeable scriptural resources as well as can provide quality answer with citation.

---

Basically, Useful resources should contain the following area:

1. Getting started: Provide source for getting basic information and knowledge about Hinduism.
2. Fundamental Texts: Provide source for getting basic and important scriptures and text of Hinduism.

   - For example: Shruti- Vedas, Upanishads, Smriti- Bhagavad Gita, Manu Smriti, Important Purans (e.g Shrimad Bhagavat), Itihas- Ramayana, Mahabharata. And the scriptures that are considered important in teaching the values in life, way of living including KarmaKanda
   - Also frequently used text for worshipping and puja
3. We can also think for providing the resources that discuss the benefits and advantages, helps in better understanding, explain correct and proper way of applying the concepts. (Including video lectures also)

---

Note: I've just proposed an example/model for the concept of useful resources. By the way I personally recommend the Indian philosopher and translator on scripture rather than western.

---

* If you prefer to provide and go with this idea then vote for this answer.