# Let's prepare the layout and contents for "Useful resources" at help center

Tags: discussion, help-center

After discussion on [About providing useful resources at our help-center](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/581/277), Now it is time to create the layout and provide content for the section "Useful resource" at help center.

So, Let's build layout and content for "Useful resource" that can provide good resources and help to the users as discussed [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/582/277).

Propose/suggest the layout with content for Useful resources.

---

<sup>Note: Contribute to this effort. Use our [chat-room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) for discussion</sup>

Comment: Tried this before, but less help from community members.

Comment: @Mr.Alien How about trying now?

Comment: Already stated, tried, less help, and now people are against mods so am not sure if it will workout well. :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien [planning](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46593213#46593213) to add small part soon.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: Implemented, It's Live Now!

> Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! Know about [the scope](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of the site take a look at tips for [asking](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions & [writing](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) good answers.
>
> Checkout the [FAQ Index](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/478/faq-index-for-hinduism-stack-exchange):
>
> - [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33)
> - [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125)
>
> In order to maintain quality of posts, we [insist](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/803) on citing some authentic and reliable sources to [backup](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2/277) the answer.
>
> [**Here**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15425) you can find list of some online sources to get Hindu Scriptures.

Note: This is under construction, you can improve this by your contribution.

Comment: I think this should be in faq  rather than help center. First of all, our off-topic pages should be updated with all the reasons. That will give clarity to new users as well as the close voters as well. Some of them are language questions, dream. That should be made clear.

Comment: There is on-topic page and off-topic page. What is the need of adding banner which contains the same links? Besides, these pages are incomplete. As I said already, they should be updated clearly. Instead of adding a banner, these should be included in specific pages like on-topic, off-topic, [ask], [answer] pages. Banners are a noise.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Let's discuss in chat...